# HashSet<User> modification, while user have only final value in 'equals/hashcode'

Tags: java, multithreading, hashset

I read some docs about `HashSets` performance and I still don't get one thing.

I have a mutable `User` class, where there's one unique, t-safe final field:

```
public User {

    // magical thread-safe, immutable int
    private final int userID;
    // some mutable stuff

    public User(int userID){
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;

        return Objects.equals(userID, user.userID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userID);
    }
}
```

I have a thread-safe immutable field - userID.

Now, I create a `HashSet<User> users` container and here starts my question.

I often iterate over this collection, to find a `User` by his nickname, ID or some other variables, and sometimes I change their values, (mutable values, not strings), but the userID still remains the same, always.

Does iterating and modifying mutable objects in this case affect the `HashSet` performance? If I have `hashcode()` which includes only one, immutable value - it should be ok, right?

Thanks very much for the help!

## Edit

Changed AtomicInteger to int - no need for atomicity, it's already t-safe

Comment: Why don't you just use `final int`? And what do you mean by "affect performance"?

Comment: Modifying from a HashSet is kind of pain.If the change will make too often and  you have an option use `Map<Integer, User> ` instead of `HashSet`

Comment: That was a good point with this final int - it would be thread-safe anyway, but it still gives no answer to the question about performance with this kind of hashCode/equals! :)

Comment: If you changed to using `int`, there is no point in using `Objects.hash` and `Objects.equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does iterating and modifying mutable objects in this case affect the HashSetperformance? If I have hashcode() which includes only one, immutable value - it should be ok, right?

Right. Since HashSet is backed by HashMap:

> If many mappings are to be stored in a HashMap instance, creating it with a sufficiently large capacity will allow the mappings to be stored more efficiently than letting it perform automatic rehashing as needed to grow the table. Note that using many keys with the same hashCode() is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Conclusion: Performance in a HashSet is mostly affected by:

- The **ratio** between the number of contained items and the collection's actual capacity.
- The **distribution** of values returned by hashCode.

(Changing the value returned by hashCode - OK, I notice this is not your case, would harm severely the behaviour of HashMap, because if an object was initially indexed by number N, changing it -externally- later to N+1 without the HashMap noticing it, would make the HashMap not finding the object in its "expected" place.)

All this said, there's something smelly in your question: You say that you  "often iterate over that HashSet". But HashSet is not to be iterated on: It is to be indexed: You should reach an object directly by calling `get` or `contains`. Iterating is a poor using of the indexing nature of HashSet.

### Finding by multiple criteria

If you need to find a `User` object by different criteria, you should add this paradigm for each filtering value:

```
public class UserContainer 
{
    private final Map<K, User> usersByKey1=new HashMap<K1, User>(1.7*finalSize);

    public void addUser(User user)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            this.usersByKey1.put(key1, user);
            ...
        }
    }

    public void User getUserByKey1(Key1 key1)
    {
        return this.usersByKey1(key1);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            this.usersByKey1.remove(key1);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

See? UserContainer is an abstraction which encapsulates all user management issues: indexing, adding, removing, etc. You can add a new indexing map for each required searching value: userName, email, etc - as long as each one of them is actually a candidate primary key for User.

Comment: Concerning the last point, I think OP needs a `HashMap` with id as key, so he can find a user directly by id. However if he wants to search by name or other information, iteration is inevitable, unless he creates other maps. which will be like adding an index on a table.

Comment: Yes, most probably he/she will need to declare one different HashMap for each different required search, as long as it might be done through indexing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As you said:
> You should reach an object directly by calling get or contains.

This complately breaks my implementation, cause I need some methods to find users in that container by other values, like name, email etc. To do it - I need to iterate over the set and as you said - this is unefficient for HashSet. What container would you recommend for me to handle this situation? I need objects to be unique and I need to provide methods to 'find objects by some values' - by extending the container.

Comment: Also, I thought about it. I simply don't need a Set - I have these values unique in Database, so I could just create an Array/Linked list and for security reasons, override add/addall methods to disallow duplicates. What do you think?

Comment: I write in Java for two years and still, when I see 5 maps with same users, my first thought is: "memory allocated 5 times". I'm such a dumb.
Thanks sir for a great solution!

Comment: No, no dumb at all. Of corse, indexing consumes memory, but not that many: User **objects** are the same, allocated just once. What consumes memory are the maps internal structures. You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks again. I have one more question. What about synchronization here? What would be the best way to ensure thread-safety on add/remove/getUserByKey()? Should I synchronize on the entire class (this)?

Comment: Ah, good point! OK; I've just included internal synchronization in the writting methods. It is not required in the getter methods, since they do not modify the object's state.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the modified fields aren't part of the hashCode/equals, this won't be a problem.

Comment: And not used in `equals(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as hash code remains the same and `equals(...)` is consistent with `hashCode()`, there will be no problems with `HashSet`. I see not problem with your code as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

The fields which are used for the comparision are only ones which matter when comparing the objects not anything else. Now in your case you are only using the id field so changing the value of other mutable fields doesn't matter even with the performance of hashset as in hashcode you used the single userid.